# cannot get http headers in local network

Tags: php, http, curl

I'm doing a pixel tracking but when I try to get the HTTP Headers using cURL, it returns this:

[image: Output]

the current code:

```
<?php
  $img = imagecreate(1,1);
  $white = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 255, 255);
  imagesetpixel($img,1,1,$white);
  header("content-type: image/jpg");
  imagejpeg($img);
  imagedestroy($img);
  $file = fopen("results.txt", "a");
  $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  $date = date("r");
  fwrite($file, "$ip from: $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] at $date");
  fclose($file);
?>
```

Comment: @AnisRétro, what web server? Apache? Nginx? PHP built-in?

Comment: I actually use Apache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First of all add line i records.txt
2. Generate Image
3. Do ob_clean(), it will remove output if warning occures
4. Give output of image
5. do not close php tag.
6. try it with browser instead of CURL because curl output should be garbase collection because output is in binary format.

PHP:

```
<?php

  $file = fopen("results.txt", "a");
  $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  $date = date("r");
  fwrite($file, "$ip from: $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] at $date");
  fclose($file);
  $img = imagecreate(1,1);
  $white = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 255, 255);
  imagesetpixel($img,1,1,$white);
  header("content-type: image/jpg");
  ob_clean();
  imagejpeg($img);
  imagedestroy($img);
```

Comment: `curl -I ...` should not be binary format, since that is just the headers

Comment: you have used curl -I it means output is inline

Comment: try with browser atleast

Comment: No, `curl -I` means "Fetch the HTTP-header only"